# Why Haskell destructure array with tuple

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I don't understand how Haskell can destructure the array to a tuple

e.g., why this works

```
head :: [a] -> a 
head (x:xs) = x
```

But this does not work

```
head :: [a] -> a 
head [x:xs] = x
```

it's unintuitive to me

Comment: what tuple? the parenthesis is purely to highlight to the parser that you're using a pattern in a function argument. You use parentheses around function arguments when pattern matching on them (with multi arity constructors).

Comment: `(x:xs)` is not a tuple. `(x, y)` would be a tuple.

Comment: Do you believe that `(True)` and `[True]` are the same value? They are not. The former is simply the same as `True`, only written with additional parentheses. The latter is a list, and is equivalent to `True : []`.

Comment: If you rename `Nil = []` and `Cons = (:)` then the first pattern is `head (Cons x xs) = ..` and the second pattern is `head (Cons (Cons x xs) Nil) = ..`. Probably not what you expect, a singleton list `[x] = Cons x Nil`.

Comment: The correction has been quietly made, but more explicitly. You're not dealing with "arrays" but with lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why this works
>
> ```
> head :: [a] -> a 
> head (x:xs) = x
> ```
>
> But this does not work
>
> ```
> head :: [a] -> a 
> head [x:xs] = x
> ```

This is a very common source of difficulty for people learning Haskell. These look similar in some cases, but mean different things:

- The type `[a]` is equivalent to `[] a`, meaning “the type of lists of zero or more elements that all have type `a`”.
- The pattern `[p]` is equivalent to `p : []` and `(:) p []`, meaning “match a list of exactly one element that matches the pattern `p`”.

Note that a list pattern with a variable at the end matches any number of remaining elements, but if it ends with “nil” `[]` then it matches a fixed number of elements. Here are some examples for lists of length *n*:

- `xs` — *n* ≥ 0 — more than zero elements; any list
- `p : xs` — *n* ≥ 1 — more than one element; non-empty lists
- `p₁ : p₂ : xs` — *n* ≥ 2 — more than two elements
- `p₁ : p₂ : p₃ : xs` — *n* ≥ 3 — &c.
- …
- `[]` — *n* = 0 — exactly zero elements; empty lists
- `[p]` — *n* = 1 — exactly one element; singleton lists
- `[p₁, p₂]` — *n* = 2 — exactly two elements
- `[p₁, p₂, p₃]` — *n* = 3 — &c.
- …

Writing `x : xs`, which is the same as `(:) x xs`, matches a list of one or more elements. Putting that in parentheses `(x : xs)` is equivalent, it’s only necessary because of precedence rules: `head x : xs` means `(head x) : xs`, which is a valid expression but not a valid pattern.

Writing `[x : xs]`, which is the same as `(x : xs) : []` and `(:) ((:) x xs) []`, matches a list of exactly one element (`[` *e* `]`) where that element matches a list of one or more elements (*e* = `x : xs`). Here are some examples:

- `let { x : xs = [1] } in (x, xs)` evaluates to `(1, [])` because:

  - `x` `:` `xs` matches `1` `:` `[]`

    - `x` = `1`
    - `xs` = `[]`
  - And these are all equivalent:

    - `[1]`
    - `1 : []`
    - `(:) 1 []`
- `let { x : xs = [1, 2, 3] } in (x, xs)` evaluates to `(1, [2, 3])` because:

  - `x` `:` `xs` matches `1` `:` `2 : 3 : []`

    - `x` = `1`
    - `xs` = `[2, 3]`
  - And these are all equivalent:

    - `[1, 2, 3]`
    - `1 : [2, 3]`
    - `1 : 2 : [3]`
    - `1 : 2 : 3 : []`
    - `(:) 1 ((:) 2 ((:) 3 []))`
- `let { x : xs = "hi" } in (x, xs)` evaluates to `('h', "i")` because:

  - `x` `:` `xs` matches `'h'` `:` `'i' : []`

    - `x` = `'h'`
    - `xs` = `"i"`
  - And these are all equivalent:

    - `"hi"`
    - `'h' : "i"`
    - `'h' : 'i' : []`
    - `(:) 'h' ((:) 'i' [])`
- `let { [x : xs] = [[1]] } in (x, xs)` evaluates to `(1, [])` because:

  - `[` `x : xs` `]` matches `[` `[1]` `]`
  - `x` `:` `xs` matches `1` `:` `[]`

    - `x` = `1`
    - `xs` = `[]`
- `let { [x : xs] = ["yo"] } in (x, xs)` evaluates to `('y', "o")` because:

  - `[` `x : xs` `]` matches `[` `["yo"]` `]`
  - `x` `:` `xs` matches `'y'` `:` `'o' : []`

    - `x` = `'y'`
    - `xs` = `"o"`
- Neither `x : xs` nor `[x : xs]` matches an empty list `[]`
- `[x : xs]` does not match `["ya", "no"]` because `x : xs` `:` `[]` does not match `"ya"` `:` `"no" : []`, because `[]` does not match `"no"` `:` `[]`
- `[x : xs]` does not match `[[]]` because `x` `:` `xs` does not match `[]`

Answer (score 4):

`(x:xs)` is *not* a tuple, `(x, xs)` is a pattern for a 2-tuple. `(x:xs)` is short for `((:) x xs)` where `(:)` is (one of the two) data constructors for a list. The other one is `[]`, the empty list.

The `(:)` data constructor has two fields: the first one (here `x`) is the head that points to the first item of the list, and the second one (here `xs`) points to the list of the remaining elements. So this looks like a *linked list*.

`[x:xs]` is a short variant of `[(x:xs)]`, so it binds with a list of lists where the outer list contains a *single* element, and that single element matches with `(x:xs)` so a non-empty list with `x` the first item of the only sublist, and `xs` the remaining elements of that sublist.